# add shortcode heading showing multiple time

Tags: php, plugin-development

Hi my code is below for adding shortcode in posts. when i am adding shortcode two times it shows me heading two times that i added in code  "Recent Posts" is there is way to show this heading only top means one time?[image]

```
/*shortcode start*/
add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'PL_recent_posts' );

function PL_recent_posts( $atts  ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'numbers' => '5',
        'order' => 'ASC',

    ), $atts ) );

    $rposts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => $numbers, 'orderby' => 'date' , 'colorss' =>     $color ) );


    if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        $html = '<h3>Recent Posts</h3><ul class="recent-posts">';
        while( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
            $rposts->the_post();
            $html .= sprintf(
                '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
                get_permalink($rposts->post->ID),
                get_the_title(),
                get_the_title()
            );
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
 wp_reset_query();

return $html;
}
```

Comment: I…don't really get it. Why would you want to show the same 5 Posts two times in the same post? 
Well, whatever.
You could add an attribute like "show_title" to toggle between showing and not showing the title. Or you could use a global var...

Comment: is there any way without attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper to your plugin output

```
if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
    $html = '<div class="pl_recent_posts">';
    $html .= '<h3>Recent Posts</h3><ul class="recent-posts">';
    while( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        $rposts->the_post();
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_permalink($rposts->post->ID),
            get_the_title(),
            get_the_title()
        );
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    $html .= '</div>';
}
```

Create a custom CSS file

```
.pl_recent_posts:not(:first-of-type) h3 {
    display: none;
}
```

And enqueue the CSS file

```
function pl_recent_posts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pl_recent_posts_style', plugins_url('stylesheet.css', __FILE__) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pl_recent_posts_styles' );
```

This doesn't completely remove it from the DOM but it will hide it from view

Answer (score 0):

1. The questions also strikes me as bit nonsensical, leading me to suspect there's actually some other unstated objective involved.
2. You might want to look at wp_get_recent_posts() for this kind of use, especially since these queries don't apparently replace or take place within the loop anyway (relatedly, not sure why you're using new query and reset.

Taking the question literally, though still a bit perplexed:

```
/*shortcode start*/
add_shortcode( 'recent-posts', 'PL_recent_posts' );

function PL_recent_posts( $atts  ) {

extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'numbers' => '5',
    'order' => 'ASC',

), $atts ) );

//colorss?
$rposts = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => $numbers, 'orderby' => 'date' , 'colorss' =>     $color ) );

if ( $rposts->have_posts() ) {

    //this could also go outside this loop (you'll always have at least 1 recent post!)
    $html = '<h3>Recent Posts</h3>';

    $add_html = '<ul class="recent-posts">';

    while( $rposts->have_posts() ) {
        $rposts->the_post();
        $add_html .= sprintf(
            '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
            get_permalink($rposts->post->ID),
            get_the_title(),
            get_the_title()
        );
    }

    $add_html .= '</ul>';

}

wp_reset_query();

$add_html .= $add_html;

$html .= $add_html;

return $html;

}
```